# Angular 4 - stop function that emitted from child component

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript

I have a parent component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  funcBoo():void{
    alert("boo");
    //return false - didn't work
  }

}
```

and the child component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {


  @Output() onArrowClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


  arrowClicked(){
    this.onArrowClick.emit(null); 
    alert('arrowClicked');
  }

  }

}
```

in the html of the parent I use the child component
with the event 'onArrowClick' like this:

```
<app-child (onArrowClick)="funcBoo()"></app-child >
```

I want to be able to stop the function arrowClicked() in the child component from keep running(the 'arrowClicked' alert won't appear), in the parent component (it's for a user which won't have access to the child component)
I tried simple return false and it didn't work.

Can you help me to understand it?

Thank you

Comment: It's not clear what you want to do exactly. Add proper explanation.

Comment: Unsure but can you pass `$event` as param to the button click and use preventDefault() or stopPropogation

Comment: Ric, I tried also but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to add an `@Input` option in order to disable emission when you want it. An example below with a `disabled` option :

```
<app-child [disabled]="parentVariableHere" (onArrowClick)="funcBoo()"></app-child >
```

And then your child component would be like :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './child.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./child.component.scss']
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() disabled: Boolean = false;
  @Output() onArrowClick: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();


  arrowClicked(){
    if(!this.disabled) {
      this.onArrowClick.emit(null); 
      alert('arrowClicked');
    }
  }

}
```